# Database character limit codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, activerecord

I can limit the size of characters of table field in mysql as simple

```
SELECT NID,LEFT(BODY, 10) AS text FROM tablename
```

but how can i get the same result in `codeigniter Active Record`
I tried this code

```
$this->db->select('NID, LEFT(BODY,10)');
$query = $this->db->get_where('tablename');
```

but not working

is it possible to make that in `codeigniter Active Record` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able make it work in Codeigniter using a syntax like this:

```
$this->db->select('NID, LEFT(BODY,10) BODY', false);
$query = $this->db->get_where('tablename');
```

as stated in: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/201014/#940615
adding 'false' to select, avoids the automatic backtics

also, after left(BODY, 10), you must add the name the new chopped field will use:

```
select('NID, LEFT(BODY,10) BODY'
```

otherwise, Codeigniter will output an Undefined property error.
I hope it works!